# Flurry push notifications on IOS, Not able to upload certificate

Tags: push-notification, flurry, flurry-analytics

Trying to implement push notifications with Flurry for our app we are getting the flowing message:
"Could not save push notification credential ValidationFailedException: Certificate environment mismatch. Your certificate for unknown does not match with production you are uploading for"

The message it self is very clear but we just can't understand what is wrong.

Yahoo Docs are not updated So we do not know if something changed or what.
It is not and issue with the p12 file password because then there is a deferent message.

1. we created an intermediate cert file in the key change with push notifications enabled
2. In the Apple developer console -> Certification -> we created a new certification for "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox and Production) in the Services section.

3.Downloaded it and opened it

4. In the flurry console in Admin -> Apps -> Flurry Push -> Push Credentials we tried to add the certificate to either dev or prod and got the message I wrote above.

Anyone can help with this.
We can't find any sort of documentation for this on the web and it is weird!

This might be a lead for the issue but can't figure it out: Your certificate for ***unknown*** does ???

10x

Comment: Can you try creating a new prod cert and uploading? If you still see the error, email support@flurry.com and we can investigate.

Comment: Hi, I already did that, Both Prod certificate and SSL Push certificate. I will contact support, 10x